# How to console.log() in server.ts file in angular ssr

Tags: arrays, angular, server-side-rendering

I am trying to debug in my server.ts file in my angular application. In my server.ts file, all regular routes use the universal search engine:

```
// All regular routes use the Universal engine
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
      { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req },
      { provide: RESPONSE, useValue: res }
    ] });
  });
```

Whenever I get directed to a url, I expect this function to be ran and the url to be logged into my browser but nothing gets logged as I hit a bunch of urls. How can I log the urls as I get directed to different urls in my server.ts file?

Comment: If you're running your universal code locally, you'll see the log statement in the console that your server is running in. If you're trying to debug remotely, you'll need a logging service, whether it's simply writing to a file or using a 3rd party

Answer (score 2):

In your `package.json` file, you will have a `build` and a `serve:ssr:<project-name>` script, see example below:

```json
     ⋮
  "scripts": {
         ⋮
    "build": "ng build",
    "serve:ssr:<project-name>": "node dist/<project-name>/server/server.mjs"
         ⋮
  },
     ⋮
```

in order to see your logs you will:

1. run `npm run build`

   - this script will create a `/dist` folder that includes the built `server.mjs` file.
2. run `npm run serve:ssr:<project-name>`

   - this script will run the built `server.mjs` file.
   - OBS! you will have to re-run `npm run build` every time you update/change your code (unless you create your own custom script that checks for changes)

Comment: you can also run `ng build --watch` and will re-build automatically on file change, but you need to run `node dist/<project-name>/server/server.mjs` manually every time the build changes, or you can have `nodemon` and automate that part as well.

I have a question how can I debug the `server.mjs`, I am also adding some custom endpoint, so I want to know how things look on node side? I am using VSCode.

Comment: @ezhupa99 , what do you mean debug? you can add logs in your ts server-files and then you can run `npm run build && node dist/<project-name>/server/server.mjs` in your terminal to see these logs. Then based on what is logged you can debug and see what is happening. But maybe I am misinterpreting your question? 

Comment: I mean to debug it properly like, adding breakpoints and stuff like that, fortunately I found the solution, but you can share any ideas.